# Transform the NFSA with transition table

Tags: matrices

Transform the NFSA with transition table

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
X&a&b\\
A&\{\}&\{F\}\\
B&\{\}&\{\}\\
F&\{\}&\{A,S\}\\
S&\{F\}&\{A,F\}
\end{array}$$

and starting state $S$ inta a DFSA and give the transition table of that DFSA. Place the letter $X$ (uppercase) in the top left corner of the matrix. Your states in the first column and inputs in the first row can be in the order of your choice.

The question then offers a $7\times 3$ matrix to be filled in.

Unsure how to transform the NFSA with transition table.

This is my answer but it is incorrect.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
X&a&b\\
\{S\}&\{F\}&\{A,F\}\\
\{F\}&\{\}&\{A,S\}\\
\{A\}&\{\}&\{F\}\\
\{A,F\}&\{\}&\{A,F,S\}\\
\{A,S\}&\{F\}&\{A,F\}\\
\{A,F,S\}&\{F\}&\{A,F,S\}
\end{array}$$

Comment: I dont understand the question at all..

Comment: Mainly, I do not see the question at all. And my eyes are usually very good at distinguishing details from the distance. Could you improve the size/formatting somehow?

Comment: it says  
Transform the NFSA with transition table 








 
X
a
b
A
{ }
{ F }
B
{ }
{ }
F
{ }
{ A,S }
S
{ F }
{ A,F }







 

and starting state S into a DFSA and give the transition table of that DFSA. 

Place the letter X (uppercase) in the top left corner of the matrix. 

Your states in the first column, and your input characters in the first row can be in the order of your choice (this does not affect your mark.)

Comment: @MathsNoobbyy: Can you at least draw the NFSA corresponding to this transition table?

Comment: why would I need to do that?

Comment: Sorry man Im confused

Comment: @MathsNoobbyy: It’s not necessary in order to answer this question, but if you can’t, that tells me that you have a more fundamental problem than knowing how to convert an NFSA to a DFSA.

Comment: Check my update

Answer (score 0):

Note: Copying my answer from a possible [duplicate of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247284/cant-do-nfa-to-dfa) elsewhere.

The only thing I can think of is that you have $\{A\}$ as a state of your DFA, and it shouldn't be there; you can't get to $A$ without being able to get to either $S$ or $F$ in addition.  After all, $\{B\}$ is also not in the DFA, because you can't get to it.  The other states look right.