# Can't do NFA to DFA

Tags: matrices

Transform the NFSA with transition table

XABFSa{}{}{}{F}b{F}{}{A,S}{A,F}
and starting state S inta a DFSA and give the transition table of that DFSA. Place the letter X (uppercase) in the top left corner of the matrix. Your states in the first column and inputs in the first row can be in the order of your choice.

The question then offers a 7×3 matrix to be filled in.

Unsure how to transform the NFSA with transition table.

This is my answer but it is incorrect [image]
Im unsure as to what I've done wrong!

[image]

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Transform a deterministic finite automata to a non-deterministic finite automata? But isn't an NFA just a DFA? (correct me if I am wrong, I learned this like 7 years ago)

Comment: I want to  Transform the NFSA with transition table

Comment: @Pedro: Every DFA is an NFA, but not *vice versa*.  So no conversion is required to make a DFA an NFA; it already is one.  But I think the problem may be mis-titled; it appears to be trying to convert an NFA into a DFA (a common exercise).

Comment: year sorry thats what I meant! NFA to DFA!

Comment: Yes, your title says DFA to NFA, anyway, was confused too. Also, it would be very nice if you could change the table such that it looks like [the one presented here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247167/transform-the-nfsa-with-transition-table). Then it is more clear. Also as Brian proposed, a picture of your automata (e.g. made in paint) makes it also more easy for us to follow. For some people like me automata are something on the back of my mind and presenting your information clear let this information come back more quickly. :p

Answer (score 0):

Note: Copied my answer to a possible [duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247167/transform-the-nfsa-with-transition-table).

The only thing I can think of is that you have $\{A\}$ as a state of your DFA, and it shouldn't be there; you can't get to $A$ without being able to get to either $S$ or $F$ in addition.  After all, $\{B\}$ is also not in the DFA, because you can't get to it.  The other states look right.